# React Native. Getting value from ref attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get value from a component but keep getting undefined refs.
Here is my code. From a function onClickSave(), I have tried to get this.refs to get a value of ref "input" in TextInputCell component but it's undefined. Is my code incorrect?

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Form, Section, TextInputCell } from 'react-native-forms';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import ActionBar3 from '../components/ActionBar3';
import * as profileActions from '../actions/profileActions';

const GLOBAL = require('../GlobalConstants');

class ProfileViewEdit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClickSave.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
  }

  onClickSave() {
    console.log('aaabd');
    console.log(this.refs);
  }

  render() {
    const title = this.props.navigation.state.params.title;
    let value = this.props.navigation.state.params.value;
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#EFEFF4' }}>
          <ActionBar3
            barTitle={title} navigation={this.props.navigation} onClickSave={this.onClickSave}
          />
            <Section
              title={title}
              //helpText={'The helpText prop allows you to place text at the section bottom.'}
            >
              <TextInputCell
                value={value}
                ref="input"
              />
            </Section>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  stateProfile: state.profile
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(profileActions, dispatch)
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ProfileViewEdit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that you are not handling events correctly. To use `this` in your events you need to bind `this`. Arrow functions bind it itself but you can bind manually to. More information is [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

> You have to be careful about the meaning of `this` in JSX callbacks. In
>   JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to
>   bind `this.handleClick` and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined
>   when the function is actually called.

Second thing string refs are not suggested anymore. You should use functional ones. More info about that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom#legacy-api-string-refs).

> **Legacy API: String Refs**
>
> If you worked with React before, you might be familiar with an older
>   API where the ref attribute is a string, like "textInput", and the DOM
>   node is accessed as `this.refs.textInput`. We advise against it because
>   string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and are likely to
>   be removed in one of the future releases. If you’re currently using
>   `this.refs.textInput` to access refs, we recommend the callback pattern
>   instead.

**Example**

```
<ActionBar3 barTitle={title} navigation={this.props.navigation} onClickSave={ () => this.onClickSave()} />

<TextInputCell value={value} ref={(ref) => { this.inputRef = ref; }} />
```